# ajax-php request in the same page

Tags: php, ajax, request

i have a html file like that:

```
<?
$q=$_REQUEST['???'];//sth. like that
echo $q;
?>

<form>
 <select name="users" onchange="showUser()">
 <option value="">Select a person:</option>
 <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
 <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
 <option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
 <option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

and i want to use the selected by onchange value in the same page in php block.

i only want to select some of the options and hold it a variable in php like $q as i indicated upon. how can i do that in the same page?

Comment: Why do you need it in php? If you only want to display, JS is enough. Else you need an ajax request to a php file that, after the needed operations, echoes back the value, which JS picks up and prints on the page

Comment: 1. build options with loop. 2. On match: value=q, add "selected"

Comment: You can obviously do that as usual. Why do you worry about the same page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a function in javascript which will handle AJAX request

your `onchange=""` function call will have the argument as `this.value` which means it will carry the value selected in select box to javascript function

In javascript function showUser it will create a xmlhttp object to execute the ajax methods "`open()`" and "`send()`"

like:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  { //For Other browsers
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  { //For internet Explorer
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

Now a function is created which needs to be executed when response is ready as

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("yourcontainerID").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
//to display the response in the html container
        }
      }
```

Now a request is sent php file and parameter can be obtained using url query string or post variable as well using `open()` method

here let assume we are using url query string hence,

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","urphpfile.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

not to recieve the "q" variable in php file you can do

```
$q=$_GET["q"];// here you may use $_REQUEST["q"] which can hadle both $_POST and $_GET
```

in ur php file....

and you are done....